# How can I delete records in a loop?

Tags: siebel

I'm writing a business service which needs to iterate all the records in a BC, and delete some of them:

```js
bc.ExecuteQuery(ForwardBackward);
var isRecord = bc.FirstRecord();
while (isRecord) {
  if (...) {
    bc.DeleteRecord();
  }
  isRecord = bc.NextRecord();
}
```

However, [DeleteRecord moves the cursor to the next one](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/OIRef/Interfaces_Reference11.html#wp1010759), so I would be skipping a record for each one being deleted, which is not what I want. Is there any standard-*ish* way to solve this?

I guess I could just make two loops, one for the checks and another for the deletion... it would work, but it just feels silly to iterate twice over the records, there has to be a better way than this:

```js
bc.ExecuteQuery(ForwardBackward);
var isRecord = bc.FirstRecord();
var list = [];
while (isRecord) {
  if (...) {
    list.push(bc.GetFieldValue("Id"));
  }
  isRecord = bc.NextRecord();
}

bc.ClearToQuery();
bc.SetSearchSpec("Id", "='" + list.join("' OR ='") + "'");  // "='1-ABCD' OR ='1-1234'"
bc.ExecuteQuery(ForwardBackward);
while (bc.FirstRecord()) {
  bc.DeleteRecord();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that DeleteRecord  does not return anything. Otherwise the logic could have been easily re-arranged with an if loop. Your logic of pushing to a list and deleting selectively looks optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution will depend directly on your if (...) condition:

- If it's a simple condition, which can be converted to a search
  expression, then you just simply can make a query and delete
  everything that was found.
- If it's a complex condition, which cannot implemented as a searchspec, then you can do this in two ways (both has its own disadvantages):
  a) Use awkward combination of DeleteRecord and PreviousRecord.
  b) Create second method that will delete single record and call it for each record that satisfy the condition, something like that

  ```
  function deleteRecord(sId:chars) {
    ...
    bc.SetSearchSpec("Id", sId);
    bc.ExecuteQuery(ForwardOnly);
    if (bc.FirstRecord()) {
      bc.DeleteRecord();
    }
  }
  ... 
  bc.ExecuteQuery(ForwardBackward);
  var isRecord = bc.FirstRecord();
  while (isRecord) {
    if (...) {
      deleteRecord(bc.GetFieldValue("Id"));
    }
    isRecord = bc.NextRecord();
  }
  ...
  ```

Your solution can be and option c), but it will not work when Id list will be too big, because such query will lead to a huge SQL statement and databases have some limitations on SQL query size (and DBA won't be happy to see such queries in logs).

I prefer option b). You can optimize it by creating a second instance of the same BC in your main function and pass it by reference to the deleteRecord function.

Comment: In this particular escenario the condition was quite simple and I moved it to a search spec, with a "while FirstRecord, DeleteRecord". I was more interested in finding out how other people does it in the complex case. I think I prefer your b) option, too, it's more clean.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing `ForwardBackward`, you could just add a `PreviousRecord` call after deleting:

```js
bc.ExecuteQuery(ForwardBackward);
var isRecord = bc.FirstRecord();
while (isRecord) {
  if (...) {
    bc.DeleteRecord();
    bc.PreviousRecord();
  }
  isRecord = bc.NextRecord();
}
```

Or simply do the loop backwards:

```js
bc.ExecuteQuery(ForwardBackward);
var isRecord = bc.LastRecord();
while (isRecord) {
  if (...) {
    bc.DeleteRecord();
  }
  isRecord = bc.PreviousRecord();
}
```

Comment: Definitely the second one looks better. However, there is a problem with both of them: "If you use the DeleteRecord method on the last record, then the cursor points to nothing". Not sure if I can do a PreviousRecord from there.

Comment: @AJPerez the first one would not give a problem then, since even if `PreviousRecord` would not work, `NextRecord` would return falsy then, I think. But yes, siebel BC's would definitely benefit from either `DeleteRecord()` return something, or having a `GetCurrent()` method or something

Comment: I thought you could be right, so I've just tried them... but something weird happens :D. For example, if I have 4 records in the BC and execute the second code (without any `if`), it deletes the 4th, skips 3, and deletes 2 and 1. Calling Previous when I just deleted the last record doesn't seem to work too well. The first code also skips one of the elements, although in this case I didn't check which one or when it's skipped.

Comment: @AJPerez that's weird indeed... I'm sorry, but I don't have an environment ready to be able to test any of this, I'm just writing from head. "Logically", it should work, but siebel is a strange beast sometimes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are are storing the value of a first record in var and then in the loop you are checking if records are presents. I suggest you go for forward and backward try.
The value of var is incremented, So, Inside the while loop place the move back an element command and so var will now store the previous element. After executing the loop. You can easily increment to the next element.

Comment: pls provide some examples